# SSRS - Drillthrough Expression

Tags: sql, reporting-services

This is my expression for my drilldown....The field where I have set my drilldown has two values
 - Vacant
 - Occupied

When vacant, it wil do this (it will do nothing and stay on the same report i.e. no drilldown.

=iif(Fields!status.Value = "Vacant", Nothing, Globals!ReportName)

But when 'Occupied' I want the drilldown to launch another report.  This is the path of the report.

/RANNNIP/FYTR Reports/FYTRReport_Detail_drill

Is it possible to have this in the same expression ?

This is my current expression - but obviosuly not working

=iif(Fields!status.Value = "Vacant", Nothing, Globals!ReportName) & iif(Fields!status.Value = "Occupied", Globals!ReportFolder /RAN NGN/FYTR Reports/FYTRReport_Detail_drill)

Comment: Hard to understand. Please explain "launch another report". Do you mean embed another report into one of your table cells? I don't think you can trigger another report to execute based on your data.

Comment: Your expression appears to have invalid syntax - the 2nd Iif does not have 3 parameters and your string starting /RAN is unquoted.